# Navigation Bar not on top

Tags: html, css

My navigation bar is not all the way up in my browser.
Look at my code and the picture you will understand!
https://ibb.co/YZZjRx8

There is a white "thing" over my navigation bar. I want the navigation bar in top!!

I deleted some <body> tags. I also deleted some other tags but nothing important!

#### My HTML-file

```html
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />

<ul class="topnav" style="position:sticky">
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### My CSS-file

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

ul.topnav li {
    float: left;
}

ul.topnav li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

ul.topnav li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    ul.topnav li {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Where is my mistake? Look at the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work if you add:

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you :D

Comment: If the answer helped you, please mark it as correct with the button under the downvote button on the left. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: gray;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /* */
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/t16zwo92/

Here's how you can create a minimal-reproducible-example

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your question and saved in this file. Please check.
It's just margin 0 for the `ul` tag.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G960GIC7YCC3